# silverlight textbox scrollbarvisibility

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a text box with verticalscrollbarvisibility set to auto.  I would like to do a test to find out if the scrollbar is actually visible during runtime.  I have tried the statement:

if (textbox1.VerticalScrollBarVisibility == ScrollBarVisibility.Visible)

but it does not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place the following extension method in static class (either place the class in the same namespace as the rest of your code or in namespace included with a `using` statement in your code file):-

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
        yield return child;
        foreach (var descendent in Descendents(child))
            yield return descendent;
    }
}
```

With this extension method available you can dig out the ScrollViewer inside the text box which is responsible for the scroll bar and test its `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility`.

```
if (textbox1.Descendents().OfType<ScrollViewer>()
  .FirstOfDefault().ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
```

Comment: Hi Anthony,

I think I may be missing something.  I get the following errors when I try to implement this:


1.)'System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer' is a 'type' but is used like a variable
2.)No overload for method 'OfType' takes '1' arguments

Comment: Oops both are actually the same problem, typed the syntax of OfType wrong,  answer adjusted